# Best way to terminate thread in my usercontrol when containing form is closed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, idisposable

Dang - 10 YEARS of C# programming and I still just can't deal with the fact that there are no C++ like destructors in this language.  99.9% of the time it is not an issue - but now it's getting me.

I have a UserControl.  That control launches a secondary thread.  I have overridden Dispose() to terminate my secondary thread and that all works.

Until....somebody forgets to call MyControl.Dispose() when closing their Form.  Then the app never closes while my secondary thread churns away waiting for a close signal that will never arrive.

It just doesn't seem right to me to have to include a help topic for something as simple as putting my control on your form - running your app - then clicking the windows close button.   Something like "YOU MUST CALL MyControl.Dispose() WHEN USING THIS CONTROL!"  (which, of course, nobody will ever read)

In my mind, controls should be able to be instantiated and automatically destroy themselves without any other interaction.   Is this not possible in C#?   Is there some way I don't know about for my control to AUTOMATICALLY know the container object has closed so I should also finalize?

Comment: Can you attach to an "OnFormClose" (or something) event?

Comment: BTW - I have solved my own problem by simply using a BackGroundWorker in my control instead of having a Thread member var and using Thread.Start().

Comment: simonlchilds: no because this is a UserControl.  Yes, the person using my control can (and should) call my Dispose() from their form close event.  But that is what I am trying to avoid.  I want to avoid training every user of my control to override their form close and call my Dispose().   

The BackGroundWorker I mentioned above seems to solve it. Though I'm not sure I understand why.

Comment: "I have solved my own problem by simply using a BackGroundWorker in my control instead of having a Thread member var and using Thread.Start()"  To achieve the same thing with manual threading, set the [Thread.IsBackground()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) property of your Thread to **true**.  Now the thread will automatically be shutdown when the application exits, just like the BackgroundWorker().

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to Idle_Mind but I couldn't flag his comment as an answer.   So I'll answer my own question and give him the credit....

To achieve the same thing with manual threading, set the Thread.IsBackground() property of your Thread to true. Now the thread will automatically be shutdown when the application exits, just like the BackgroundWorker().

Answer (score 0):

But there are destructors in c#.
If you have a dispose function, just use it like here, where the dispose is called in the destructor if it was not called before.

[Disposing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx)

Comment: Been there - done that.  Dispose() gets called (or doesn't get called) at the whim of the GC.  Maybe call it.  Maybe not.   Simply closing your app does not ensure Dispose() will be called.   In fact - my test show that closing your app will NEVER call Dispose()

Comment: Yea, but the destructor must be called by closing the app and there you call your disposing if it was not called manually before.

Comment: Chris - nope.  Even the ~MyControl() {}  method (the destructor) does NOT get called when closing the app.  I know, weird right?   It all hinges on the mood of the GC.  And if you got a lot of memory - the GC is almost never "in the mood" to call the destructor.